# How do I pre-hide something in preparation to expose it in a jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a button div that I've attached a jQuery animation to, that exposes/hides it upon some other event.

It works nicely, but I'm unclear on what style elements of the div they are altering, so, I'm not sure how to set up its CSS so that it starts out hidden and then becomes exposed when the event that starts the animation is kicked off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you are wondering what properties to put on in the base page code. In that case, just put a simple `display:none;` on the button element - jQuery is smart enough to take care of the rest.

Comment: ah... lovely. thanks. I wasn't sure if that would prevent it from showing up at all.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel The only way that would happen is if you used `display: none !important;`, in which case it's still possible to change its visibility, but is much harder. So you obviously wouldn't want to use `!important` :)

Comment: No prob - glad I was able to help. Really, you can't go wrong with jQuery. I sometimes feel like it knows what you want even when you don't.

Comment: I should just test this, rather than ask, but maybe for posterity, I will... will hide() (or display:none) pre-toggle it to the hidden state so that when I call animate() it will animate IN, or is there something else I need to do to get it hidden in a way that the first animation out will bring it out of hiding in an animated way?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Yup just `hide()` or `display: none`. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple options:

With css

```
display: none;
```

Or jQuery

```
.hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display: none;` thats what jquery sets it to once it has been 'hidden'